# How to save form data after hook form alter?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to hook into the Social Content module to add taxonomy tags. I've got the fields showing up where they are supposed to, but I don't understand how to actually save the field data.

Here's my hook form alter:

```
function upup_taxonomy_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  // target a single form
  if($form_id == "social_content_form"){
    $form['client_taxonomy'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => t('Up&Up Client'), 
        '#maxlength' => 160, 
        '#autocomplete_path' =>'taxonomy/autocomplete/field_up_up_client', 
        '#default_value' => '', 
        '#weight' => -1,
        '#description' => 'Enter a client name.'
      );
    $form['contact_taxonomy'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => t('Up&Up Contact'), 
        '#maxlength' => 160, 
        '#autocomplete_path' =>'taxonomy/autocomplete/field_up_up_contact', 
        '#default_value' => '', 
        //'#weight' => 0,
        '#description' => 'Enter a contact name. This is optional.'
      );
    $form['#submit'][] = 'upup_taxonomy_form_submit'; 
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Now i have function for `upup_taxonomy_form_submit`, but I don't know what's supposed to go inside there. I want to save the taxonomy id in this field.

```
function upup_taxonomy_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
    //what goes in here?
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to save the data? Custom DB table? In the variables table? Somewhere else? You need to decide that first, then it'll be easy to point you to the right functions to use

Comment: The social content module creates nodes from tweets, facebook posts, etc. I want these nodes to have a taxonomy id when they are created that I can filter with using views. Where would I have to store that?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid, I guess it would make most sense to store it alongside the rest of the data that module saves, but I'm not familiar with it so I don't know what it uses for storage. If you want to save data on a node field that's easy: `$node->field_foo[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'bar'; node_save($node);`, but how/when you would do that in this context is beyond me without reading the whole module

Comment: It looks like the module is saving the rest of the data in separate tables in the database, for instance the table `field_data_field_tweet_link` is the link to the tweet and it's columns are entity type, bundle, deleted, entity_id, revision_id, language, field_tweet_link_url.

Comment: Those are field data tables, so go with the approach I mentioned. It's not clear where you'd get the details of the node from, though, that'll probably require some digging through the social module